# Laravel 4 transactional rollback for 500 error

Tags: transactions, laravel-4

If I have a function which is not declared and resulted in a 500 error and this function is called within the try block, will the insertions done before the function be rolled back?

When I tried the following code, the 500 error is not handled by the catch.

```
DB::connection()->getPdo()->beginTransaction();

try
{
   $helper = new Helper;
   $helper->functionThatIsNotDeclared();
   DB::connection()->getPdo()->commit();
}
catch( \Exception $e)
{
   DB::connection()->getPdo()->rollBack();
}
```

Is there anyway to handle the 500 error properly?

Thanks in advnace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fatal errors in PHP terminate the current code "stack" and jump directly to the shutdown handler, so they avoid try/catch blocks. You could register a fatal error handler:

```
App::fatal(function() { DB::getPdo()->rollback(); });
```

But this would likely not work well if there was no transaction started when another fatal error occurs.

The general advice here is to just avoid fatal errors as a whole. Fatal errors indicate a bug in your code as opposed to exceptions which are more "expected" errors happening in your applications.

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether a method exists in PHP by using `method_exists()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

Your code would look something like this:

```
DB::connection()->getPdo()->beginTransaction();

try
{
   $helper = new Helper;

   if(method_exists($helper, 'functionThatIsNotDeclared')) {
      // The method exists, do something
   } else {
      // The method doesn't exist, do something else
   }

   DB::connection()->getPdo()->commit();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
   DB::connection()->getPdo()->rollBack();
}
```

Though I think the reason why you were getting an error is because of your `catch()` - I believe you meant to type `catch(Exception $e)` rather than `catch( \Exception $e)`.